# getting error "Undefined variable: guard" when redirect route in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, middleware

I am using middleware in 'laravel 5.5'. Everything is working fine, but when I am trying to redirect dashboard I am getting an error **Undefined variable: guard**.
I don't know what's wrong with this file.

**middleware(RedirectIfNotGuestUser.php)**

```
class RedirectIfNotGuestUser
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
      if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('user/login');
      }
      return $next($request);
   }
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('user/login','Guestauth\LoginController@login');
   Route::middleware(['guestuser'])->group(function () {
   Route::get('account/dashboard', ['as'=>'account.dashboard','uses'=>'Guest\DashboardController@home']);
   });
});
```

Comment: I think you should add  $guard = null in the handle function as a parameter

Comment: Do you have any another guards ?